# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::open()

Tags: forms

I am building a web app with Laravel and I get this error once I run the application:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::open()
```

Some mention to use "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*" as "illuminate/html": "^5.0" no longer uses Form. However, in both cases I get the error message above. Can you advise me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm migrating a legacy application and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your `composer.json` file uses `"laravelcollective/html": "^5.0@dev"`, as the `illuminate` version is no longer supported.

Be sure to add `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` in your `config/app.php` file as a providor, as well as the aliases:

```
'HTML'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
```